# Invalid character constant

Tags: java, character, constants

I need to do this:

```
if(']' == body.charAt(body.length()-1) || '锛� == body.charAt(body.length()-1) || '銆� == body.charAt(body.length()-1)){
    score++;
}
```

And I get an error saying that: Invalid character constant

Why? How can I get over it?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This is a real question - no need to vote to close. And it's got a real and valuable answer

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your source code, it seems like it is Java.
Also, this seems corrupted:

```
'锛� == body.charAt(body.length()-1)
```

and probably should read

```
'锛' == body.charAt(body.length()-1)
```

With this in mind, you have 2 options:

1. Make sure that your source code is saved as UTF-8. There are few ways to check this, on Windows I would recommend using Notepad++ and select save as *UTF-8 without BOM* option.
2. Use `\uHHHH` syntax for your non-ASCII constants. As far as I can tell, your 锛 character should be encoded as `U+951B`, so you can use this instead:
   `'\U951B' == body.charAt(body.length()-1)`

Comment: +1 for explicit Unicode codepoints. If you cut and paste non-ANSI characters into many editing tools they will often get corrupted

Comment: Hi, mvp. Thanks for your reply. I have corrected my code with your approach of using Notepad++. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you like answers or they solve your problems, you should upvote and/or accept them. This is how this site works